# Papers on the gamma function

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, gamma-function

Which papers on the gamma function would you recommend? I would like to study it to be able to understand the riemann zeta function, among things.

Comment: Find yourself a good complex analysis book to start with. I personally like [Bak & Newman](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441972873) where they introduce $\Gamma$ and $\zeta$ from scratch, show some properties of them (like the $\Gamma$ reflection formula) and in the end derive their analytical continuation. IIRC they also shows a proof of the prime number theorem. This should give you all the basic knowledge you need.